# How to add a field to a django model on Google app engine using django-nonrel?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models, django-nonrel

I deployed a django project on Google app engine using django-nonrel. Now I want to update the schema of a model named "Good" by adding an integer field named "Pause".

```
class Good(models.Model):
    pause = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

To my understanding, this should be done by updating each existing instance manually. After searching, I wrote the piece of code below.

```
from goods.models import Good
from google.appengine.ext import db

def UpdateSchema():
    query = list(Good.objects.all())

    to_put = []
    for p in query:
        p.pause = 0
        to_put.append(p)

    if to_put:
        db.put(to_put)
```

And the error returned is: 
"BadArgumentError: Expected one of (<class 'google.appengine.ext.db.Model'>,);"

It seems that db.put only accepts google.appengine.ext.db.Model instance. How can I change a django model instance to a google.appengine.ext.db.Model instance?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing GAE SDK calls and django calls is painful.

I'd do the following.

```
query = Good.objects.all()

for p in query:
    p.pause = 0
    p.save()
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. I thought I had to directly manipulate GAE data store.